# type of apple vs type of apples

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects, countable-nouns

There are 4 types of apples: sweet, sour, spicy, and tangy. Referring to the sweet type

1. This type of apple is prevalent in northern regions.
2. This type of apples is prevalent in northern regions.

Which of the above two is correct? I think (2) is correct. We are classifying apples. Apples are not singular. So, type of apple***s*** seems more appropriate.

Comment: 1. is OK, but not 2.  "This kind of apple is fine" / "These kinds of apples are fine" / "These kind of apples are fine" are all OK, but not *"This kind of apples".

Comment: Types of apple with an s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael Swan, in *Practical English Usage,* Third Edition says

> When we are talking about one sort of thing, we can use *sort of, kind of* or *type of* followed by a singular noun.
>
> > This **sort of car** is enormously expensive to run.
> > I'm interested in any new **type of development** in computer science.
>
> Singular *sort of, kind of* and *type of* can also be followed by plural nouns, especially in an informal style.
>
> > I'm interested in any new **kind of developments**...

So, usually and particularly in formal writing, it's singular. It **seems** to be that you might use the plural if it's appropriate when *sort of* is omitted. Thus

> This car is enormously expensive to run.
> I'm interested in any new development...
> I'm interested in any new developments...

Swan even goes on to include "these sort of cars" in his treatment, which does indicate how singular and plural are used [but note the singular *sort*!] It sounds odd to this native speaker, though, and I don't think I'd ever use a plural demonstrative; consequently I'd only use the singular "sort of apple".

Comment: This question is a dupe. See my close reason.

Comment: @Robusto Indeed. Since my answer appears to answer Kosmonaut's lingering doubt too, this question should probably be merged with that one. I'll mark it as a duplicate for now.

Comment: It can be summed up as: "This kind of dog is dangerous" / "These kinds of dogs are dangerous" / "These kind of dogs are dangerous" are all fine., but not *"This kind of dogs is dangerous".

Comment: This is the only answer to include a credible reference (though eric.cheung did add some statistics hinting at idiomaticity).